# Change source KML on Spinner Item selection in Android Studio project

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to get 2 spinner activities change the source kml file for Google map annotation. I am not sure, how should I access the GoogleMap object created at onMapReady method inside the 2nd level spinner object onItemSelectListener object.

I'm using Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2

My objective is that the defailt (on load) map selects India and New Delhi in the 2 spinners, and show India options in 2nd spinner.
Once user selects for eg. UK then 2nd spinner should show options for UK, and map goes to (select the corresponding kml) the first option selected for UK in the 2nd spinner

Here's my strings.xml file (corresponding part only):

```
    <string-array name="locationall">
    <item>India</item>
    <item>UK</item>
    <item>USA</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="locationInd">
    <item>New Delhi</item>
    <item>Kolkata</item>
    <item>Mumbai</item>
    <item>SBangaluro</item>
    <item>Chennai</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="locationInd">
    <item>New Delhi</item>
    <item>Kolkata</item>
    <item>Mumbai</item>
    <item>Bangaluro</item>
    <item>Chennai</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="locationUK">
    <item>London</item>
    <item>Edinburgh</item>
    <item>Manchester</item>
    </string-array>
```

And here's how I am calling... please forgive me I stopped when I got the error message, I am not sure how should I access the GoogleMap object (googleMap) inside the spinner's setOnItemSelectedListener. Please help me.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    assert mapFragment != null;
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    KmlLayer layer;
    try {
    layer = new KmlLayer(googleMap, R.raw.newdelhimap, this);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    layer.addLayerToMap();
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng nDl= new LatLng(28.7, 77.2);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(nDl));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(nDl, 11.9F));

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mainspinner);
    Spinner spinnerSub = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.subspinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptermain = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
    this,
    R.array.locationall,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
    );
    adaptermain.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner.
    spinner.setAdapter(adaptermain);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterKol = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
    getApplicationContext(),
    R.array.locationKol,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
    );
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears.
    adapterKol.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterTrip = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
    this,
    R.array.locationTrip,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
    );
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears.
    adapterTrip.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterInt = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
    this,
    R.array.locationInt,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
    );
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears.
    adapterInt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView,
    View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    // Object item = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position);

    // Depend on first spinner value set adapter to 2nd spinner
    if(position == 0){
    spinnerSub.setAdapter(adapterKol);
    spinnerSub.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    if(i==0){
    KmlLayer layer;
    try {
    layer = new KmlLayer(googleMap, R.raw.newdelhimap, this);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    layer.addLayerToMap();
    } else if (i==1){
    KmlLayer layer;
    try {
    layer = new KmlLayer(googleMap, R.raw.kolkatamap, this);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    layer.addLayerToMap();

    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
    });

    } else if (position == 1){
    spinnerSub.setAdapter(adapterTrip);
    }else {
    spinnerSub.setAdapter(adapterInt);

    }

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {// do nothing
    }

    });
    }
```

Below is my activity xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rl"
            android:padding="0dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/btn"
                android:text="Next"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/mainspinner"
                android:background="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_light"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn"
                android:tooltipText="Select Place"
                />
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/subspinner"
            android:background="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mainspinner"
            android:tooltipText="Select Place"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>


    </fragment>
```